# Scrapy failes to parse on pages with long response time

Tags: scrapy

I am requesting and parsing the search results of an eCommerce website with Scrapy 2.x. Unfortunately the page has a response time of often more then 5s. It appears that it returns a 200 without any search results present and the parser starts parsing the page, resulting in 0 extractions as the results are not present yet.

How can one increase the time to render, or the delay?

This is the target page:
https://shop.apotal.de/keywordsearch?SEARCH_STRING=fester%20stuhlgang&VIEW_INDEX=0&VIEW_SIZE=40

Scraping is pretty straight forward:

```
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]},
            callback=self.parse_item,
        )
```